# Line breaks not going through

Tags: php, css, database, alignment

Alright so for my site I am allowing my users to have a description of themselves or whatever they like, however when I attempt to make breaks using [ENTERKEY] into the `<textarea>` it looks like this:

```
Hello, I am John Smith.
Phone#: (123)456-7890
I enjoy web-browsing.
```

When I return to the page it looks EXACTLY the same (It puts their current description in the edit box). This is what I want. I look in the PHP database and it still looks the same. Again it is what I want. However on the profile page It looks like this

```
Hello, I am John Smith. Phone#: (123)456-7890 I enjoy web-browsing.
```

It is contained inside a div with these style tags and like so

```
        <div style="width: 250px; min-height: 50px; margin: auto; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; padding: 2px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
            <?php echo $description; ?>
        </div>
```

Im curious why it does this any help would be appreciated :D.

Comment: browsers expect html (nl2br())

Comment: Web browsers do not render line breaks. Use [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) to convert newlines into HTML `<br>` elements.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php‎

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `white-space:pre-line` to your `<div>` Or, use:

```
<?= nl2br($description); ?>
```

Remember that HTML needs `<br />` for line breaks, not `\n` or `\r\n` (like your `<textarea>` is collecting). So you can either tell HTML to pay attention to those new lines using `white-space`, or force the `<br />` using [`nl2br`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a newline in a textarea, it gets stored as `\n`, however, HTML does not honor `\n` linebreaks, which is why everything shows up in a single line when inside a div.

To fix this, you have to convert the `\n` to `<br />` (using [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) )which HTML recognizes:

```
<div style="width: 250px; min-height: 50px; margin: auto; font-weight: normal; text-align: center; padding: 2px; margin-bottom: 5px;">
    <?php echo nl2br($description); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you take a regular line break and try to render it as HTML, HTML ignore the whitespace character.  You need to explictily use `<br>` (or `<br/>` depending on DOCTYPE) to create a line break in HTML.

The easiest way to do this in PHP is by using `nl2br()` function in PHP on output.